# jqGrid: Multi-column filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

filterToolbar method added search field for each column, but i need to one global search field for filtering by three custom columns(like a this [screenshot](http://habrastorage.org/files/c79/75b/e02/c7975be02108447fbc94fda42436b06a.png)).

For example:

```
grid.jqGrid({
url: '/url/to/json',
datatype: 'json',
loadonce: true,
colModel: [
    { label: 'Last Modified', name: 'lastModified', width: 15, sorttype: 'date' },
    { label: 'Campaign Name', name: 'name', width: 35, sorttype: 'text' },
    { label: 'Camp ID', name: 'id', align: 'left', width: 10, sorttype: 'integer' },
    { label: 'Advertiser', name: 'advertiser', width: 15, sorttype: 'text' },
    { label: 'Status', name: 'status', width: 10, sorttype: 'text' },
    { label: 'Flight Dates', name: 'startDate', width: 15, sorttype: 'date' }
],
autowidth: true,
...
```

I need to sort the table by 'name', 'id' and 'advertiser' attributes. I think this is a trivial task, but could not find a ready-made solution.

Comment: you want to search in 3 colums with value of one text box? And you need  to sort your tables only by one column at a time?

Comment: yes. the search should be carried out in several columns('name', 'id' and 'advertiser' for example)

Sort results is carried out by means of a jqGrid default functionality.